# Android Gradle: can't find symbol variable

Tags: android, sdk, drawable

I have a error when building with gradle that says, `error: cannot find symbol variable [image_name]`. I'm using `ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.[image_name])` I have been googling all over until I found this method to get a drawable without using a deprecated method or setting my min sdk to 21. But now, gradle says it can't find a symbol variable. I have my image in the drawable folder.
If you need anything, comment please.

EDIT:

res:
drawable (images under here)
drawable-hdpi
...

My class:

```
import [package_name].R;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class HomeActivityFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String[] titleData = {"[TEXT]", "[TEXT]", "[TEXT]"
    };

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(titleData));

    Drawable[] imageData = {
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.seminar_cross_th),
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.media_th),
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.praise_th)
    };

    ArrayList<Drawable> images = new ArrayList<Drawable>(Arrays.asList(imageData));

    HomeAdapter homeListAdapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), titles, images);


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_list);
    listView.setAdapter(homeListAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.exampleApp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.exampleTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.exampleApp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
}
```

Comment: What drawable folder have you used? That error means that the drawable is not being added to `R.drawable` for some reason. Have you tried cleaning and the building?

Comment: It was in the default drawables folder. Yes, I have tried cleaning and building.

Comment: What R class are you importing in the class that throws the error? Post some of the code and directory structure so we can get a better idea what is happening.

Comment: I did not import the R class, but when I do, I do get a error when I get drawable.

Comment: You have to import the R class otherwise you'll get this error. Please post the relevant information I asked for in my previous comment.

Comment: It is posted for you.

Comment: I remember reading a post that mentioned importing your own package's R package, so I have done that. I will now attempt running.

Comment: Can you post the full class where the error occurs? That snippet doesn't help at all and looks like it has typos.

Comment: Yes, you always import your own packages R class.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, copy and pasting isn't very nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have imported `android.R`, which only includes core framework resources. You need to change this to `com.example.package.R`, where `com.example.package` is your applications resource package name.

EDIT (MashedPotatoes): I forced a JPG file to be PNG without proper conversion, that's what caused the errors. But the original error was caused by importing `android.R`, not `com.example.package.R`, so marking this as correct.

Comment: I have changed it, but android studio says it's an unused import

Comment: Oddly enough, I changed everything that calls for a resource to use my packages resource package, but I still get the gradle error.

Comment: Maybe add your `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` so we can see if something is going on there.

Comment: Done, I tried removing the optional dependencies, but I still got the error.

Comment: The `build.gradle` looks OK, can you post the rest of the manifest?

Comment: that is the entire manifest... i just put some png files into the drawable foler, just so you know

Comment: Some of the manifest is missing. If that really is the whole manifest it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89490/discussion-between-mashedpotatoes-and-kane-oriley).

Comment: You saved my day.. Was trying to debug this for past 4-5 hrs.

Comment: Great Answer ever... :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the error had nothing to do with imports and simply was dealing with a .JPG that had a .PNG file extension. Renaming the file extension fixed the problem.